# Multiplying by the Square Root of Twelve to calculate annual standard deviation

Tags: standard-deviation

[image]

I failed to see the mathematics truism. Can someone care to elaborate.

Answer (score 4):

If $$ X_1, X_2, \dots, X_{12} $$ are i.i.d. (stochastic independent identical distributed) it holds $$ var(\sum X_i) = \sum var(X_i) = \sum var(X_1) = 12var(X_1) $$. now take the square root to get the stated result.

Comment: But aren't we suppose to take the average when calculating variance? Does that mean the yearly fluctuation is larger than tge monthlt fluctuation, which doesn't sounds right to me. Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you take the variance of a sum? If Z=X+Y and X and Y are independent r.v. then var(Z)=var(X)+var(Y) . There is no average.

Comment: @jxhyc Average of variance? This makes no sense.